# non static tooltip issue jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, tooltip

I have this code already working:

```
<div class="tippytrip">Here's a link!</div>
<div class="tippytrip">Here's a link!</div>
<div class="tippytrip">Here's a link!</div>
<div id="tooltip-container">The tooltip!</div>

$('.tippytrip').hover(function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    console.log(offset)
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    $('#tooltip-container').css({top:offset.top, left:offset.left + width + 10}).show();
}, function(){
    $('#tooltip-container').hide();
});

.tippytrip {cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:40px; width:80px; border:2px solid #ccc; padding:5px}
#tooltip-container {position:absolute; padding:30px; background:black; color:white; display:none}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5LSxG/

But it only works for one tooltip container with that id, I want it to be dynamic, either the caller or the div that is called.

Comment: what do you mean by "either the caller or the div that is called." ?

Comment: Why don't you simply change the text/style of the tooltip? http://jsfiddle.net/HmmC8/

Comment: Andreas because it will be a div with html information | karthikr i want several tooltips that could be called by several links/images/divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use data attributes to make it dynamic.

```
<div class="tippytrip" data-tip="Tip 1">Here's a link!</div>
<div class="tippytrip" data-tip="Tip 2">Here's a link!</div>
<div class="tippytrip" data-tip="Tip 3">Here's a link!</div>
<div id="tooltip-container">The tooltip!</div>

$('.tippytrip').hover(function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    console.log(offset)
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    $('#tooltip-container').html($(this).data('tip')).css({top:offset.top, left:offset.left + width + 10}).show();
}, function(){
    $('#tooltip-container').hide();
});

.tippytrip {cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:40px; width:80px; border:2px solid #ccc; padding:5px}
#tooltip-container {position:absolute; padding:30px; background:black; color:white; display:none}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LSxG/124/)

If you are wanting to have multiple tip containers for each link then you can do something like this:

```
<div class="tippytrip" data-tip="1">Here's a link!</div>
<div class="tippytrip" data-tip="2">Here's a link!</div>
<div class="tippytrip" data-tip="3">Here's a link!</div>
<div class="tooltip-container" id="tooltip-container1">First Tip</div>
<div class="tooltip-container" id="tooltip-container2">Second Tip</div>
<div class="tooltip-container" id="tooltip-container3">Third Tip</div>

$('.tippytrip').hover(function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    console.log(offset)
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    $('#tooltip-container' + $(this).data('tip')).css({top:offset.top, left:offset.left + width + 10}).show();
}, function(){
    $('#tooltip-container' + $(this).data('tip')).hide();
});

.tippytrip {cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:40px; width:80px; border:2px solid #ccc; padding:5px}
.tooltip-container {position:absolute; padding:30px; background:black; color:white; display:none}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LSxG/125/)

Comment: thats making the tooltip: "Tip1" etc. thats not whats intended. the container is suposed to be outside the caller like my example where the tooltip-container its the actual tooltip

Comment: I guess I am confused by your question. The tooltip-container is still the tool tip. I took your example word for word and just added the functionality to change the html in the tool tip based on what was being hovered. I have updated the question to show how to have multiple tip containers per link based on the comment on your question

Comment: God I love you :D im testing it out now

Comment: im not being able to replicate this :\